# Extremely Slow Netezza (Database) Batch Inserts

Tags: java, sql, performance, insert, netezza

I am using batch inserts and prepared statements to insert data into Netezza. However, the performance is extremely slow. Below is my code:

```
final int batchSize = 1000;
int count = 0;
for (final MyClass object: myList) {
    ps.setString(1, object.getOne());
    ps.setString(2, object.getTwo());
    ps.setString(3, object.getThree());
    ps.setString(4, object.getFour());
    ps.setString(5, object.getFive());
    ps.setString(6, object.getSix());
    ps.setString(7, object.getSeven());
    ps.setString(8, object.getEight());
    ps.setString(9, object.getNine());
    ps.setString(10, object.get10());
    ps.addBatch();
    if(++count % batchSize == 0) {
        ps.executeBatch();
    }
}
ps.executeBatch(); // insert remaining records
```

Does anyone know how I could speed this up?

Comment: What amount of time is "extremely slow" and what load times are you expecting?  Inserting data into a data warehouse takes time.

Comment: Second Gilbert's request.  What times are you actually getting for your batch of 1000?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I am getting about 1-2 rows per second with the above code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insert statement batches **will not** be performant on `Netezza` the overhead per query will limit the efficiency of these operations.  I recommend dumping your data to flat files and executing a `nzload`/`external table insert`  For an example please refer to [Transient External Tables](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.load.doc/c_load_transient_external_tables.html).

Comment: Got this to work using transient external tables. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As you may already be aware, the Netezza JDBC driver may detect a batch insert, and under the covers convert this to an external table load.

As you can see from the sample runtimes here, the singleton inserts using a non-batch prepared statement are very slow, while the inserts run using executebatch scale quickly upward with the batch size.

```
start of call to testSingletonInserts() with batchSize = 100
exec time for batch-size 100: 8193ms
end of call to testSingletonInserts()

start of call to testBatchInserts() with batchSize = 1000
exec time for batch-size 1000: 190ms
end of call to testBatchInserts()

start of call to testBatchInserts() with batchSize = 10000
exec time for batch-size 10000: 734ms
end of call to testBatchInserts()

start of call to testBatchInserts() with batchSize = 100000
exec time for batch-size 100000: 1763ms
end of call to testBatchInserts()
```

Generally speaking I would not recommend a batch size of less than 10,000.

One important diagnostic point is to check a JDBC trace or the pg.log on the Netezza system to verify that external tables are being implicitly called for you.

If you see an entry like this, then you are *not* getting the benefit of implicit external tables through the JDBC driver.

```
2015-08-08 12:52:50.640127 EDT [13898]  DEBUG:  QUERY: insert into testload (c1,c2) values (next value for testload_seq, 96)
```

If you see an entry like this, then you are getting an external table.

```
2015-08-08 12:52:51.078404 EDT [13898]  DEBUG:  QUERY: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE bulkETL_13898_0 ( c0 nvarchar(5) )  USING (  DATAOBJECT('/tmp/junk')  REMOTESOURCE 'jdbc'  DELIMITER '     '  ESCAPECHAR ''\'  CTRLCHARS 'YES'  CRINSTRING 'YES'  ENCODING 'INTERNAL'  MAXERRORS 1 QUOTEDVALUE 'YES' );
2015-08-08 12:52:51.086081 EDT [13898]  DEBUG:  QUERY: insert into testload (c1,c2) values (next value for testload_seq,bulkETL_13898_0.c0)
2015-08-08 12:52:51.101234 EDT [13898]  DEBUG:  transaction 1411711 started dbos txid 0x3dc5c
```

If you find you are not getting implicit external bahavior with your batch execution, try making sure autocommit is turned off on your connection.

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
```

Comment: I have only 32k rows, and even setting a batch size of 10k, it would take hours to complete at my rate.

Comment: In this case you are definitely not getting the implicit external table behavior.  Perhaps it's because autocommit is enabled?

Comment: @JohnRoberts  i am facing the same issue, i had to insert millions of records and i tried with Batch size of 10 K and 100 K. It still took hours to finish. Auto commit is false. What should i do get the  implicit external table behavior?